# Footer not staying at the bottom of the page AGAIN

Tags: html, css, footer

I have started a new website, new code, new design however the footer will not stay at the bottom of the page again.
I attempted to use the working code from my last post but that didn't work, so I guess I have to create a new post.

This is my code:
[JsFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/o9bbwhyc/)

```
#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
right: -2px;
left: 10px;
background: red;
color: black;
```

}

As you can see that is is clearly not working because the footer is half way up the page. P.S - The reason why that massive white space is there is because there is meant to be an image there.

If you have any fixes then please say :)

Thanks in advanced

Unique

Comment: May be of use here: www.cssstickyfooter.com

Comment: for sticky footer, you need to have position: fixed

Comment: Clarify your question, what do you mean by at the bottom? If you want the footer to stay at the bottom of the page, then just put it as the last element. Do you want a sticky footer that always docks at the bottom of the viewport? Be specific, edit and question and be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you only want the footer under `#about-me`, just remove `position: absolute` from `#about-me`

Second update: http://jsfiddle.net/o9bbwhyc/4/

Further, there is an error in your HTML syntax (fixed in fiddle):

```
<div id="slider">
<center>
...
</div>
</center>
```